# Azure Backup - How does Azure backup perform Block level incremental backups

Tags: azure, backup

I understand Windows Azure Backup Agent performs incremental backups by tracking file and block level changes and only transferring the changed blocks, but my question is how does it track those changes?

The reason I ask is we are using Azure Backup as a off-site backup only, and are still planning on using our current Backup Appliance to backup locally.

I want to make sure that neither backups will conflict with the other, or mark that a file has been backed up on one system, and prevents the changes from being backed up on the second system.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Backup agent leverages USN journal capability of file system to find the changed files.  Ensure that latest Azure Backup agent is installed.